# The tag [arithmetic] should be a synonym of [calculation-puzzle], not [mathematics]

Tags: discussion, tags

I created [calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle) specifically to apply to puzzles that involved calculation as their primary form of mathematical reasoning (as mentioned in [this question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-should-we-do-with-math-and-calculation-puzzle) from the private beta).

Somehow, the tag [arithmetic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) has been merged into the [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) tag in general rather than [calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle). Since it's not possible to try to redefine it through the normal synonym process, I thought I'd bring it up here.

Comment: The still-in-its-original-state description of the (recently redubbed) [`mathematics`](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/mathematics/info) tag is indeed daunting enough to distinguish it from calculation and arithmetic and makes me wonder why it has been overapplied in general.

Comment: @humn It's meant as a general tag for any puzzle that involves mathematical reasoning. Arithmetic/calculation puzzles are a subset of that, so while every arithmetic puzzle could (and should) indeed be tagged as a mathematics puzzle as well, it's still a useful subdistinction to make.

Comment: (nod of acknowledgment and agreement, am adding a [related comment](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5016/do-we-need-to-reorganize-the-puzzle-suffix-tags#comment10681_5016) elswehere)