# Tag for IQ-test-like questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I looked around meta, and it seems this came up before. It seems there [used to be such a tag, but it was removed](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5675) for various reasons:

- One reason is that it is 'meta' and describes the 'origin' of the puzzle rather than the content.
- One reason is that low-quality/off-topic questions should be flagged/closed/deleted rather than tagged.

Might it not be possible to describe an origin-independent, quality-independent 'type' like *here's a (usually 3x3) picture grid with a corner missing, and here's some more pictures, which one is supposed to fill in the blank?* Such a thing isn't necessarily from an iq-test, nor is it necessarily low-quality.

Even if we don't call it [iq-test](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iq-test), isn't there  *something* taggable here, even for just specifically 3x3, it seems there are enough of them to justify their own tag, I think?

But I'm not really a meta user, and don't fully understand the previous history on meta of this issue.

Comment: Confession: my selfish reason is to put an ignore on it. This doesn't mean I think they're off-topic. I have 'valid' tags on ignore, that's what it's for right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a [progressive-matrix](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/progressive-matrix) (see [Raven's Progressive Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven%27s_Progressive_Matrices)) tag for the "picture grid with a corner missing" type of problems?

For other type of sequences that also appear on IQ tests, there's already the [sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence), [pattern](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern), and [number-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-sequence) tags.

Comment: oh, thanks! I was not aware of the term 'progressive matrices'.

Comment: well, no responses... so I'll start doing it and see if it catches on, or if I get yelled at :-)