# What's the difference between the tags [arithmetic] and [calculation-puzzle]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I was seeking into tags until I found these tags:

[calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle) which states "*A puzzle that involves numerical calculations, such as multiplication and addition.*"

[arithmetic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) which states: "*For puzzles involving addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division.*"

There is no difference between these two tags (except for wording).

Can the tag [arithmetic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) (Qx106) be the synonym of [calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle) (Qx669)?

Comment: And furthermore, what's the difference between Black Thunder and [Dark Thunder](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/56681)?

Comment: I don't know about it. Thats a coincidence. I got almost same rep on Stack Overflow as he got here.

Comment: @jafe You might wanna see this ;) https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86701/little-lost-robot#comment252133_86701

Comment: Hehe, looks like someone beat me to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made [arithmetic] be a synonym of [calculation-puzzle]. There was an argument for doing it the other way around, but we had a lot more [calculation-puzzle] puzzles than [arithmetic] ones, and some calculation puzzles aren't strictly about arithmetic. If it's widely felt that "arithmetic" is a better name, there are ways to change the name.

Answer (score 6):

According to the person who created the calculation-puzzle tag:

> When I created the [calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle) tag, I made it specifically to refer to those problems that involved numerical calculation or arithmetic as part of the solving process. – Joe Z. ([source](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/209/41973))

The arithmetic tag did not exist back then, it was created later. Seems clearly redundant to me.

"Arithmetic" is probably a clearer name for the tag, though. Maybe make calculation-puzzle a synonym for that?

Comment: I think that the tags could be distinct but unfortunately the tag descriptions are the same :( . Like [tag:arithmetic] could be a meta version of [tag:calculation-puzzle] and more to do with the process of processing numbers rather than just processing numbers (although that seems a bit redundant anyway)